# Homeless woman uploaded into computer

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds, singularity, mind-uploading

I vaguely remember an SF novel from the 1980's or early 90's about a poor, maybe homeless, Black woman who gets uploaded into a computer as an experiment. I think the title was the woman's name (?). Kind of an early take on the "Lawnmower Man" idea. That's about all I can recall, unfortunately; it was one of those "great-idea-that-deserved-a-better-writer" books. Anyone know it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [*Lady El,*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3150842-lady-el) by Jim Starlin and Daina Graziunas. First published June, 1992.

From the *GoodReads* site:

> A poor woman killed in subway accident is given a second chance at
>   "life" when her brain is harvested by a government operation in an
>   attempt to link human minds with computers.

[image]

Comment: That's the one. Thank-you!